# Possible to ubuntu mirroring mouse keyboard?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

is there a anything available that can "mirror" keyboard and mouse inputs to multiple windows? Like I have a "master"-window in which I click and write and the input from there gets send to several "slave"-windows.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can always run screen or tmux in several terminal windows and your updates will appear in each terminal where you are attached to the same session.

That's for *terminals*.  If you want to do that with a GUI, a different tag should be used.